# Matching panel data at time t-1 and time t Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, finance

I am currently working on a project involving financial data. I have a data frame containing a number of fundamental variables as well as stock returns for many different companies, just like this:

```
           year     ticker      tot_assets      return
0          1999       AAPL          10.345      0.1294
1          2000       AAPL          10.988      0.1577
2          2001       AAPL          12.003      0.0782
..          ...        ...             ...         ...
34521      2017       GMBO           0.893      0.2209
34522      2018       GMBO           1.206      0.1001
..          ...        ...             ...         ...
200344     2012         ZZ           3.789      0.0032
200344     2013         ZZ           3.021     -0.0346
```

What I have been trying to do without success is, to match each company `ticker` with another one in the df based on the closest `tot_assets` value on year t-1. Thus create two new columns, where one has the `ticker` of the matched company as well as its `returns` at time t. So we are doing the matching at time t-1 but the reported returns are for time t.

So it should look like something like this:

```
           year     ticker   tot_assets   return   m_ticker   m_return 
0          1999       AAPL       10.345   0.1294         AA     0.0890     
1          2000       AAPL       10.988   0.1577         AA     0.1666     
2          2001       AAPL       12.003   0.0782       TSLA     0.3470
..          ...        ...          ...      ...        ...        ...
34521      2017       GMBO        0.893   0.2209        AIR     0.0032
34522      2018       GMBO        1.206   0.1001       CECE     0.1123
..          ...        ...          ...      ...        ...        ...
200344     2012         ZZ        3.789   0.0032       ASKI     0.0432
200344     2013         ZZ        3.021  -0.0346       ASKI     0.0339
```

I hope I was clear enough in my explanation :P Maybe that's the reason why I have been having troubles! I cannot show you the df because it has more 200'000 observations - but I hope that the concepts above help :)

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What did you try to solve this?

Comment: So you want to find the divergence between last years closest match to this years current result? I feel like including the second tickers data in the original set would be beneficial.

Comment: @BjörnB Yeah i did but its not the right result, I can only get a match year to year - I don't know how match at t-1 but then get return for t

Comment: @LuckBox I am trying to do kind of an event analysis, so i need to match the firms on total assets value at time t-1 but then compare their returns at time t

Comment: I feel being able to pass a number of test cases is key to providing the most succinct answer. I feel it would be even more beneficial to provide the 2nd most closest ticker in the original dataframe as well as the closest to confirm the code works as intended. Providing your most recent attempt would also be appreciated.

Comment: @LuckBox I am following another paper's methodology and they have done this way, so thank you for your suggestion, but just to keep things simple we should keep it to the closest

Comment: this was the code for my attempt, but I repeat, it is not correct:
df = df.merge(df, on='year', suffixes=['', '_closest']).query('ticker != ticker_closest')
df['diff'] = (df['tot_assets'] - df['tot_assets_closest']).abs()
df = df.sort_values('diff').drop_duplicates(['year', 'ticker'])

Comment: Can you explain how it is not correct? Can you do this by editing your post with your code and the result and explain why the result is incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

This should get you the ticker of the firm with the closest match of tot_assets in year - 1. Hopefully, you only need to run it once to create the dataset. Otherwise, you'll have to investigate faster alternatives.

```
import numpy as np

def closest_match(row, df):
    '''Uses absolute values and argmin to find closest match'''
    try:
        last_year = df.loc[df.year == row.year - 1, :]
        absvals = np.abs(last_year['tot_assets'] - row.tot_assets)
        return last_year.iloc[absvals.argmin(), last_year.columns.get_loc('ticker')]
    except Exception as e:
        return None

df['ticker_closest_tot_assets'] = df.apply(closest_match, args=(df,), axis=1)
# then look up return based on year, ticker_closest_tot_assets
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks for your code, unfortunately it doesn't really do the job as it only creates a column with 'None' variables :P

Comment: Sorry - should've been ```last_year.columns.get_loc``` instead of ```last_year.get_loc```.